# Is this inheritance? If so what is it doing?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have a Qt this application with a QMainWindow and I am using OpenCV cv::VideoCapture. My QMainWindow subclass declared in my header file as follows:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
private:
    cv::VideoCapture cap,cap1;
};
```

In my mainwindow.cpp file I then, in my constructor, initialise `cap` and `cap1` as follows:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent), cap(0), cap1(1),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

The crux of this question is: what am I doing here? Is this simple inheritance? I'm trying to solve my naiveté.

Comment: `class MainWindow : public QMainWindow` this inheritance, yes.

Comment: You should at least post some real code.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is real code...

Comment: Well, your class has no constructor `MainWindow(QWidget*)`, so your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: I think putting the whole class in would add too much noise to the question. I believed the question could be understood using only the code provided. Is this not the case?

Comment: It is good that you post a minimal example, but it should not have gratuitous errors in it. Otherwise it is not clear whether you are trying to find out why your code doesn't compile or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is declaring the class `MainWindow` with member variables `cap` and `cap1` that are both `cv::VideoCapture` objects. This is using inheritance, since `MainWindow` is declared as a subclass of `QMainWindow`.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
private:
    cv::VideoCapture cap,cap1;
};
```

This is defining your explicit constructor. It is doing initialization of your member variables using an initializer list.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent), cap(0), cap1(1),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Comment: *What* explicit constructor? There isn't one ;-)

Comment: It isn't a default constructor, because it takes a `QWidget*` pointer as an input. I guess it's not a full explicit constructor because you can't pass in `cap` and `cap1` initializers, but I wasn't sure what to call it.

Comment: But the class has no such constructor. That's what I was alluding to.

Comment: Oh you mean in the header file? Yes you are correct none of the constructors, destructors, etc are declared in the class header.

Comment: This answers the question. It has allowed me to go and look into initialiser lists to understand the code.